# RxJava: blocking until retry

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java

I'm trying to learn reactive programming and as a first "real" application I've settled on a simple IRC client with [RxJava](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava) and [RxNetty](https://github.com/Netflix/RxNetty).

I'm currently stuck on retrying another server, if the first one fails. So, I have an [`Observable<Server>`](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/wiki/Observable), which consist of the servers of a network. It can be setup using [`.repeat()`](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/wiki/Creating-Observables#repeat), so it repeats the servers indefinitely. Now, how do I make this a blocking one, so that only one is being used at a time and it would go to the next one only if `RxClient::connect` fails or the connection timeouts?

While other solution would be to use a domain, which redirects me to different server each time I connect and just use [`.retry()`](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators#wiki-retry), I'm interested in solving the problem in the reactive way.

Connecting to all the servers (without [`.repeat()`](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/wiki/Creating-Observables#repeat)) works fine, but that's not what I want:

```
servers
    .map(x -> RxNetty.createTcpClient(
        x.getAddress(),
        x.getPort(),
        PipelineConfigurators.stringMessageConfigurator()))
    .flatMap(RxClient::connect)
    .onErrorFlatMap(x -> Observable.empty())
    .subscribe(this::handleConnection);
```

Comment: Do you absolutely has to have the list of servers as `Observable<Server>`? I think, it's better to have just a list of those, from which you pick up next one when previous fail.

Comment: No, I just thought it would make sense. Yeah, a list would probably be better.. I actually have something written down, but it's not a full solution yet. The progress is a bit slow, but I'm hoping I can answer the question at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `concatMap` instead of `flatMap`. The next server will thus only be used if `RxClient::connect` completes or errors:

```
servers
    .map(x -> RxNetty.createTcpClient(
        x.getAddress(),
        x.getPort(),
        PipelineConfigurators.stringMessageConfigurator()))
    .concatMap(RxClient::connect)
    .onErrorFlatMap(x -> Observable.empty())
    .subscribe(this::handleConnection);
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems I had overlooked the documentation of `flatMap` and I didn't know `concatMap` existed until recently.